# Confused about second-order difference scheme for non-linear PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I want to solve the following PDE on $[0,T]\times \mathbb R$ using an explicit finite-difference scheme

$$-\partial_t u(t,x) - \frac 1 2 \sup_{a\in [1,2]} a^2 \partial_x^2 u(t,x) = 0,$$
where $u(T,x) = 1_{[0,\infty)}(x)$, $\lim_{x\to \infty} u(t,x) = 1$ and $\lim_{x\to -\infty} u(t,x) = 0$.

I came up with the following scheme

$$-\frac{U(i,j) - U(i-1,j)}{\Delta t} - \frac 1 2 \max_{i=0}^{n_a} a_i^2 \frac{U(i,j+1) - 2U(i,j) + U(i,j-1)}{\Delta x^2} = 0$$

where $U(i,j) = u(i\Delta t, j\Delta x)$ and $a_i = 1 + i/n_a$.

But there are some things that don't make sense

- how do I use the boundary conditions correctly? I can iterate backwards or forward in $j$, but each time I can only use one of the latter two boundary conditions.
- *how can this be made explicit? $U(i,j)$ appears in the maximum when I try to compute $U(i,j)$.* I think I solved this: just solve for $U(i-1,j)$.

Comment: Many people find it useful to switch to a forward problem using the change variables $\tau  = T-t$. If you then use forward differences in the new time variable $\tau$ (like the one you have written down) you will not have that problem.

Comment: @PierreCarre Can I just use backward differences for the $\partial_t u(t,x)$ term instead, or is this not the right idea? - Regardless, I don't see how inverting time answers my bullet points.

Comment: I only mentioned the conversion to a forward problem because you are using forward differences in time. You can keep the backward problem but switch to a backward difference scheme.

Comment: You get $\sup_{a\in[1,2]}a^2v=\max(v,4v)=\begin{cases}4v&{\rm for }~v\ge 0\\v&{\rm for }~v<0\end{cases}$, there does not seem to be a need to discretize $a$ the way you did. Is there more that depends on $a$ in that expression?

Comment: @LutzL Uh no. Nothing else depends on $a$ - Thanks, that seems obvious now.
But can I find out whether $v \geq 0$ or $v < 0$ before computing $U(i,j)$?

Comment: Nevermind, I realize my mistake now. I tried to solve for $U(i,j)$, I should solve for $U(i-1,j)$ instead...